# GtkScrolledWindow container sends its child a size allocation with a negative coordinate

Tags: gtk, cairo, gtk3, gtk2, custom-widgets

I'm porting a custom Gtk+ widget from Gtk2 to Gtk3, and I'm observing that with the latter, I'm getting [size_allocation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-size-allocate) calls from the parent widget (a GtkScrolledWindow) which have an `allocation` with a negative Y coordinate.

This causes my widget to freak out and do stupid things obviously. If I ignore the calls that contain negative coordinates, everything seems to work fine.

So the questions are:

- Is this a gtk bug?
- If not, in which circumstances should a parent send negative coordinates?
- Why does this happen in GTK3 but not GTK2?

It happens with both gtk+ 3.6.4 (the one that comes in Ubuntu 13.04) and 3.8 (Ubuntu 13.10). Will test a higher version soon.

Comment: Curious, can you share the test you use and which produces the allocation "issue"? Really curious on this.

Comment: sure, I'm actually reducing it to have the smallest testcase possiblem, I'll link to it here as soon as I have it

Comment: @drahnr I finally replied to my own question with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was about how the widget was modifying its [GtkAdjustment](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkAdjustment.html) values, required to implement the [Scrollable GInterface](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScrollable.html).

It seems to come from the fact that Gtk3 appears to be much more "liberal" in accepting weird values. Read the whole story in [the commit message of the bugfix](https://git.gnome.org/browse/hyena/commit/?h=gtk3&id=0745bfb75809886925dfa49a57c79e5f71565d08) (open source, yeah!).